# Field Calculator VB Script Codeblock IF statement syntax is wrong?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, field-calculator, vbscript

I can't figure out why the syntax is wrong in Field Calculator ArcMap 10. The complete codeblock is

```
Dim CapitalDia As Number
Dim TwagDia As Number
Dim X As Number

CapitalDia = [New_Pipe_S]
TwagDia = [DIAMETER_1]

If CapitalDia= 0 Then
 X = TwagDia
Else
 X = CapitalDia
End If
```

And then, the bottom window is

```
Final_Dia = 
X
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "as Number" is what's causing the error. Just use "dim X"

```
dim X

if [New_Pipe_S] = 0 then
 X = [DIAMETER_1]
else
 X = [New_Pipe_S]
end if
```

Comment: It worked! I have no idea why, but it did, thanks!

Comment: In version 10, support for VBA was dropped but you can still use VBScript. Dimensioning a variable as a particular object type is VBA.