# What's wrong with this VBscript in field calculator - ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vbscript

The code fails when run

What I try to do is to fill a field "CLASSNAME"(created text field) according to field "Value"'s value.

If the value in "Value"(raster's by default field) is 1, then in "CLASSNAME" is 1 or whatever, and so on if the value in "Value" is 2,3,4...etc.

I'm working on a raster's attribute table

I saw other questions and answers, none of them answers mine.

[image]

Comment: Please ask a question.

Comment: Could you please expand on the question being asked? Does the script fail? What error does it give? Are your field set up correctly? Text and Numbers?

Comment: Not sure about the `elseif`, you can simply use `else`. Other than that, as @Keagan Allan hinted at, make sure your field data types are correct. In your example, both `[Value]` and `[val]` are set up as `Text`. If this is not the case, try to convert them within the codeblock or set the fields up correctly. And by the way: similar question here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44008/field-calculator-vb-script-codeblock-if-statement-syntax-is-wrong?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Your vba syntax is incorrect.  An `elseif` requires you to specify the `if` part eg

```
If [Value] = '1' Then 
    val = '1'
ElseIf [Value] = '2' Then
    val = '2'
Else val = '3'
End If
```

If you're only wanting `1` or `2` then you need to use `Else` rather than `ElseIf`

```
If [Value] = '1' Then 
    val = '1'
Else val = '2'
End If
```

Additionally, if you are looking at numeric fields, you might want to remove the quote marks around the numbers

```
If [Value] = 1 Then 
    val = 1
Else val = 2
End If
```